# Switch Button Sides Owl date Time Picker

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Want to switch the sides of the cancel and set buttons in angular ng-pick-date-time. Figured out how to change the labels but stuck with this. Is it possible ?

[image: switch sides of the buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.owl-dt-container-buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```